Proof using Farkas's lemma... $x$ is an optimal point if and only if $c_N^t - c_B^t B^{-1} N \geq0$
Consider the following problem:
\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize } c^t x\\
\text{subject to } A x = b\\
x \geq 0
\end{align*}
where $A$ is an $(m \times n)$ matrix of rank $m$. Let $x$ be an extreme point with corresponding basis $B$. Furthermore, suppose that $(B^{-1}b > 0)$. Use Farkas's theorem to show that $x$ is an optimal point if and only if:
\begin{equation*}
c_N^t - c_B^t B^{-1} N \geq 0.
\end{equation*}
Can anyone help me with this problem please, all my attempts have been failed, I rewrote the problem as
\begin{equation*}
\min c_B^t x_B + c_N^t x_N \quad \text{subject to} \quad (B \; N) \begin{pmatrix} x_B \\ x_N \end{pmatrix} = b, \quad x_B, x_N \geq 0
\end{equation*}
but I haven't come up with anything useful at all... the demonstration from right to left is automatic.

Which version of Farkas's Lemma?

I have used this: "One and only one of the following systems has a solution" : $Ax \leq 0, c^T x >0$ or $A^T y = c, y \geq 0$

This is a sketch of a proof rather than a full proof. But it is too long for a comment.
$x$ is a solution is equivalent to the non existence of a feasible direction that (strictly) decreases the objective value. This can be done as follows: $x$ is a solution if and only if
$$
  \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    c^T x' < c^T x \\
    A x' = b \\
    x' \geq 0
  \end{array} \right.
$$
has no solution in $x'$. Since $Ax = b$ and $x_N = 0$, it is possible to write the above condition with $\delta x = x-x'$ and obtain the equivalent condition
$$
  \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    c^T \delta x > 0 \\
    A \delta x = 0 \\
    \delta x_N \leq 0
  \end{array} \right.
$$
Now apply a usual trick ($z = 0$ if and only if $0 \leq z \leq 0$) and then Farkas lemma as you wrote in your comment.

Could you give me a hint of what's next, what you sent me seems perfect to me. But then when using Farkas I get that $y$ exists such that $A^T y = c, y \geq 0$ , but then I don't know how to continue, at least a clue would help me a lot

You should be writting down in detail what is the $A$ and $c$ in your case. And then work around the obtained equality. Another usefull trick: if $u \geq 0$ and $v \geq 0$, then $u-v$ may be negative.
